# Find out whether W is a subspace or not.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Could you please walk me through the process of finding out whether

$w=\{(x,y,0,z^2)|x,y\in R,z\in Z\}$

is a subspace or not.

I got it in an exam and didn't know how to conquer the problem, also I couldn't find a similar problem almost anywhere.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$0 \in w$, so that's an alright start, but if we are taking this as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^4$, consider closure under scalar multiplication.  In particular, the scalars come from $\mathbb{R}$, but the fourth coordinate of the points in this set can only be an integer.

There are also issues with closure under addition: given any $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$, do we always have $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$ for some $c \in \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: The other answer demonstrates another problem with scalar multiplication, $+1$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Clearly $(1,1,0,1) \in w$, but what about $2\cdot(1,1,0,1)=(2,2,0,2)$?

Comment: So, your saying it is closed under multiplication, and the zero vector is in there, right?, what about closure under addition?

Comment: The zero vector is indeed in there; but this example should show it is *not* closed under scalar multiplication. The last component should be $z^2$ with $z\in\mathbb{Z}$, right? But $z^2=2$...